# Edit in jqGrid using dropdowns for foreign keys

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Simple task in jqGrid. I am trying to edit table with foreign key. Example:

```
Users  - slave table, used to build dropdown

 Id, Username
 1, ME
 2, YOU

Roles - fact table, main table in grid

 Id, UserId, RoleName
 100, 1, BEGINNER
 101, 2, EXPERT
```

It is easy to join both tables in backend and show correct grid to user.

```
USERNAME, ROLE

ME, BEGINNER
YOU, EXPERT
```

It is easy to configure dropdown like {1:ME,2:YOU}, that will work OK on add/edit.

BUT

In Ajax call used for saving data, there will be something like

```
Id=101, Username=2, RoleName=EXPERT
```

This is not correct and I do not know how to change it. On SAVE, the column name should be USERID, not USERNAME, when column type is dropdown (select).

```
Id=101, UserId=2, RoleName=EXPERT
```

I do not know how to configure jqGrid to use alternate column name for saving data.

Please help, I am trying to solve it few days already.

Comment: Of course, I can solve it in backend (get USERID value from USERNAME parameter in Ajax call), but I am building some kind of general editor, I can not use this workaround.

Comment: It is a good idea if you post your code - I mean your jqGrid setup and if possible some demo data. You  can use jsfiddle for this purpose. This is a preferred way for solving the problems.